# XLST referencing another child node

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm attempting to add a child node referencing another child node.  In the below example I'd like to populate `<AcctID>` from `<AcctDtl>` into `<Position>`.  I'm doing this as MS-Access only imports child nodes into separate tables without a way of referencing/linking the tables.

```
<AcctFncl xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="fsrv" xsi:schemaLocation="fsrv Rec.xsd" Version="27">
  <CreateDate>20151101</CreateDate>
  <EffectDate>20151031</EffectDate>
  <FnclRec>
    <AcctDtl>
      <MgmtCode>XXX</MgmtCode>
      <AcctID>123980</AcctID>      
    </AcctDtl>
    <Position>
      <FundID>5268</FundID>
      <TotalUnAssigned>50</TotalUnAssigned>
      <TotalAssigned>0</TotalAssigned>
      <AveCost>10</AveCost>
      <DivOpt>1</DivOpt>
    </Position>
   </FnclRec>
</AcctFncl>
```

should look like:

```
<AcctFncl xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="fsrv" xsi:schemaLocation="fsrv Rec.xsd" Version="27">
  <CreateDate>20151101</CreateDate>
  <EffectDate>20151031</EffectDate>
  <FnclRec>
    <AcctDtl>
      <MgmtCode>XXX</MgmtCode>
      <AcctID>123980</FundAcctID>      
    </AcctDtl>
    <Position>
      <AcctID>123980</AcctID>      
      <FundID>5268</FundID>
      <TotalUnAssigned>50</TotalUnAssigned>
      <TotalAssigned>0</TotalAssigned>
      <AveCost>10</AveCost>
      <DivOpt>1</DivOpt>
    </Position>
   </FnclRec>
</AcctFncl>
```

---

I've been trying to create a XSLT to do this but I think I'm in over my head here.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Position">
        <FundPosition>
            <AcctID><xsl:value-of select="../AcctDtl/CreateDate"/></AcctID>         
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </FundPosition>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Sorry, that should read <AcctID>123980</AcctID>.  My mistake.  The XML is coming from a third party system, and I'm attempting to import it into MS Access and have a key to link both child tables on import.  Access imports the separate tables, but no common key to link them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the major problem you're having is that your XML input is in the default namespace `fsrv`, but your XSLT doesn't handle it.

In order to match those elements in your XSLT you'll have to bind that namespace to a prefix and use that prefix in your XPaths.

In the example below, I used the prefix "`f`", but you could use something else.

Example...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:f="fsrv">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="f:Position">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()|../f:AcctDtl/f:AcctID"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Demo: http://xsltransform.net/bEJaofi

Comment: That worked!  I'm not sure exactly how the namespace works (or how it's used in XML files), reading up on it now so I can understand this better.  Also thanks for showing me the xlstransform.net site, also very useful compared to the Notepad++ I'm using now...

Comment: @NOCARRIER - You're very welcome! +1 for a great first question. Here are a couple of good resources on namespaces: http://www.jclark.com/xml/xmlns.htm https://stackoverflow.com/a/25830482/317052